# jQuery API Usage

Tags: jquery, html

Using jsFiddle, I'm trying to test out the `jQuery(...)` function

```
<html>
  <body>
   <script>
     var section = jQuery("<div></div>");
     $("<p>This is a paragraph</p>").appendTo(section);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why won't this code automatically render a HTML page with "This is a paragraph?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add section to the document.  As it is it is just in a variable.

```
$('body').append(section);
```

Comment: @Kevin Because you haven't selected jQuery from the list of libraries on the left

Comment: thank you, Hogan and Richard Dalton. works - http://jsfiddle.net/WegBv/14/ I'll accept answer when available

Answer (score 1):

See my example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9PaTE/

`$(document).ready()` was missing and you need to `.appendTo('body')`

Comment: is the onReady() part required due to the speed of using onReady rather than onLoad?

Comment: Without the `.ready` the script will execute before the elements exist in the DOM which means there is nothing to `appendTo`. OnLoad works as well I believe but I normally use .ready within JQuery.

Comment: so, if "This is a paragraph" shows up, then I got lucky? Is it a race condition then?

Comment: AFAIK yes. It's always better to use `$(function() { });` or `$(document).ready(function(){});` to ensure the script has run after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: @Kevin - webnoob is exactly correct above -- never fear using jQuery's document ready feature -- it will just cause tears otherwise.